# Concise way to set axis label font size in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, label

I am looking for the most concise way to set axis labels and their font size.

I am aware I can do this:

```py
ax.set_xlabel('X axis', fontsize = 12)
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis', fontsize = 12)
```

I also know I can use this command to set the labels instead:

```
ax.set(xlabel = 'X axis', ylabel = 'Yaxis')
```

However, if I try:

```py
ax.set(xlabel = 'X axis', ylabel = 'Yaxis', fontsize = 12)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: There is no AxesSubplot property "fontsize"
```

Can I denote the fontsize within the `set` method?  I'd like to tidy up my code a bit and be as concise as possible.

Comment: You can't set the fontsize in `ax.set()`. You can change it globally with the `rcParams`, e.g. `plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 12` but this changes the default behaviour for all plots.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could change the label for each "axis" instance of the "axes". The text instance returned by "get_label" provides methods to modify the fonts size, but also other properties of the label:

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid()

# set labels and font size
ax.set_xlabel('X axis', fontsize = 12)
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis', fontsize = 12)

ax.plot(numpy.random.random(100))

# change font size for x axis
ax.xaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(20)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ax.xaxis.label` or `ax.yaxis.label` also return a `matplotlib.text.Text` object, so you can call `set()` or `set_size()` on it to change the fontsize (you can also change the position with the former).

```py
ax.xaxis.label.set_size(20)
```

A working example:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
ax.plot(range(10), range(10))
ax.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Value')
ax.xaxis.label.set(fontsize=20, position=(0.9, 0))
ax.yaxis.label.set(fontsize=15, position=(0, 0.9))
```

[image: result]